# Integral of a random process over time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am currently learning stochastic calculus, and while the entire thing is supposedly about defining $\int g(s) dX(s)$ where $X$ is a stochastic process, I don't even understand something like $\int X(s) ds$.

The problem originates in stochastic differentials, where we want solutions to $$X(t) = \int X(s) ds + \int g(s)dW(s)$$
where e.g. $W$ is a Wiener procesc. My book states the above, then proceeds to define the second term ("Ito integral"), and then ends the chapter. But what is the first term?? What is $\int X(s) ds$? How would I calculate such a thing?

X(s) is never given to us concretely, so how could we take its integral?

Comment: The first term is just an ordinary Riemann integral. You're right that it would be hard to actually write it down, but why is that a problem for defining a stochastic differential equation?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, $$\int X(s)ds$$ is just a standard integral.

However, this notation suppresses something else that the integral depends on. $X$ is a stochastic process, so it is actually a function of time and some underlying source of uncertainty. That is, $X$ is actually the function $X(t,\omega)$ where $\omega$ lies in some probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$.

Hence, for a fixed $\omega$ (think of this as fixing the realisation of the stochastic process), we can compute the integral as we normally would. The integral is then a random variable defined on the same probability space $X$ is.

Comment: What if $$ X : [0,T] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
is an almost-surely continuous stochastic process? How is the integral defined when, for some fixed $\omega$, the map $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is not continuous?

Comment: @Joker123 this case should be included in my answer. Is there a reason it isn’t?

Comment: If the sample path is not continuous, it might not be integrable.

Comment: @Joker123 yes. This definition assumes that the sample path is integrable. IIRC standard assumptions (e.g. cadlag paths) are enough to guarantee this, but you’ll want to double check that. I’m not familiar with any definition of an integral of the sample path when the sample path is not integrable.

Comment: Makes sense. I am still learning myself about stochastic calculus. What about the assumption, that X is only a.s. cadlag? Is this a common assumption?

Comment: @Joker123 it is common. That should be enough for $X$ to be integrable a.s., which is all you really need.

Comment: But if $X$ is integrable only a.s., then how is the integral defined on the null set on which $X$ might not be integrable? Is the integral in this case just tactily set to $0$ ?